# Write avro file in HDFS - exists

Tags: java, apache-kafka, hdfs, avro

Currently i'm learning spark streaming and avro, So  my first example is,  read a Spark RDD and build Generic record , create avro file, this file i should write  in HDFS. Now I can open avro file and i  does append to file  of HDFS  exists?

This code write an avro file, but when i try  add or append, it's failed. I am using java 8 for this

```
public static void saveAvro(GenericRecord record, Schema schema) throws IOException {

        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> bdPersonDatumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
        DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(bdPersonDatumWriter);

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/poc/ResultHDFSTest.avro"),
                conf);
        Path F = new Path("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/poc/ResultHDFSTest.avro");
        fs.setReplication(F, (short) 1);

        if (!fs.exists(F)) {
            System.out.println("File not exists.. creating....");
            OutputStream out = fs.create(F, (short) 1);
            System.out.println("OutputStream create.");
            dataFileWriter.create(schema, out);
            System.out.println("dataFileWriter create.");
            dataFileWriter.append(record);
            System.out.println("dataFileWriter append OK {0} .");

        } else {
            //Here fail, not open file.. avro stored in HDFS
            System.out.println("File exists....");
           // I want to add information to an existing avro file.
            dataFileWriter.append(record);
            System.out.println("dataFileWriter append OK {1} .");
        }
        dataFileWriter.close();
        System.out.println("dataFileWriter closed.");

    }
```

Stack trace for append exist file avro HDFS:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: not
> open
> at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.assertOpen(DataFileWriter.java:88)
> at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:311)
> at com.test.avro.App.saveAvro(App.java:83)
> at com.test.avro.App.main(App.java:55)

The DataFileWriter appendTo method only accepts a File java.nio. Is what I am trying to do correct or is there another way?

**Edit 1.**
I want to add information to an existing file.

The first code snippet shows the implementation you are trying to make to create the avro file. Here my frament code of spark streaming:

```
JavaStreamingContext jssc = sparkConfigurationBuilder
                .buildJSC(sparkConfigurationBuilder.buildSparkConfiguration());
    
    jssc.sparkContext().checkpointFile("c:\\tmp");
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = sparkDriverUtils.getKafkaProperties();        
    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(sparkDriverUtils.getTopics().trim().split(","));// 1 o more topics        
    LOGGER.warn("Lista de Topics: " + topics.toString());
```

...

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));
//This DSTream resulto to avro..
JavaDStream<Transactions> transactionsDS = transactions.map(f-> {
            Transactions txn = jsonMapperUtil.rowToTransaction(f);
            LOGGER.warn("Retornar  : JavaDStream<Transactions>");
            return  txn;
        });
```

Now transactionsDS result  i  want to save as avro file in HDFS. I have a question, JavaStreamingContext i can get o create SparkSession for  a Dataset or or should I change how I subscribe to the kafka broker?

Regards.

Comment: Why are you using RDDs or low level Java API? Spark has built-in Avro support ... https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html

Comment: Thanks, i see the url, SparkSession it can suscribe to kafka  broker with streaming same as Java InputStream? or same as Java InputStream? get an SparkSesssion?

Comment: Are you using Kafka though? Seems like you are only using HDFS here. Are you using Confluent Schema Registry? Or read any of the Cloudera blogs on Spark/Flink with Kafka + Avro?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using Cassandra, Kafka + Kafka connector(Lenses  as Source) and Spark streaming  and i want to save as avro my results  in HDFS.  Now i working with workaround for  first save  to local system and after move to hdfs, but i'll review  Sql Spark with streaming.

Comment: I would use Streamsets or Nifi instead of writing Spark code for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DataFileWriter appendTo method only accepts a File java.nio

Correct. Avro has no connection to HDFS Paths.

In order to "append to HDFS files", you need to download them locally, then *overwrite* their whole contents

---

Besides this, you mention Spark Streaming, but no part of the shown code is actually using a Spark API call

Comment: Edit my question, I added the spark snippet. Regards.